# Flutter Firebase Analytics: Track page changes with onGenerateRoute

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics

I have firebase analytics enabled for my application and I am trying to get the firebase debug-view to show my page changes. With the code below, currently nothing is being tracked, and I don't understand why. I have followed the firebase documentation for tracking page-views, but apparently I'm missing something when it comes to using onGenerateRoute.

My main:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();
  static FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer =
      FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: "localhour",
        onGenerateRoute: router.generateRoute,
        initialRoute: '/',
        navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[observer],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My generateRoute function:

```
Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
  switch (settings.name) {
    case '/':
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RootPage());
      break;
    case '/login':
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage());
      break;
    case '/home':
      var user = settings.arguments;
      return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => HomePage(
                user: user,
              ));
      break;
    case '/store':
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => StorePage());
      break;
    case '/store-details':
      var argument = settings.arguments;
      return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => StoreDetails(
                storeDetails: argument,
              ));
      break;
  }
}
```

I have used analytics before to track page changes automatically in a previous app but used the "routes" method in my main function. Can someone explain why I am not getting any feedback using this method above? Do the screens have to be named explicitly? (Which I have also tried, but unsuccessfully)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hey if you're still looking for an answer to this, it's because your not pushing the name into the MaterialPageRoute.

So in your generateRoute function:

```
  '/login':
      return MaterialPageRoute(
         builder: (context) => LoginPage(),
         settings: RouteSettings(name: settings.name));
      break;
```

That'll push the name to Firebase Analytics for you. Just add it for each case in the switch.

Comment: Hey, I actually forgot about this post and found a similar solution elsewhere. But you get the winning tick. Thanks.

Comment: How can I have access to the 'FirebaseAnalytics' object that I have in 'MyApp' inside 'generateRoute'?

Comment: Hey @RonyTesler, there's a couple of ways you can do this but I prefer Dane Mackier's solution, here's his article: https://www.filledstacks.com/post/firebase-analytics-and-metrics-in-flutter/

Answer (score 0):

So, @TyrellJames already gave a solid answer above, but here is my solution that I used. I ended up changing the structure of my code entirely in order to add in the routeName value so Firebase actually knew what my pages were called:

```
Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
  switch (settings.name) {
    case RootRoute:
      return _getPageRoute(
        routeName: settings.name,
        viewToShow: RootPage(),
      );
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Then I the _getPageRoute function:

```
PageRoute _getPageRoute({String routeName, Widget viewToShow}) {
  return MaterialPageRoute(
    settings: RouteSettings(
      name: routeName,
    ),
    builder: (_) => viewToShow
  );
}
```

This pretty much is what @TyrellJames did, mine is just the long way round.